# Develop on Oculus Go using Java and OpenGL

Tags: java, virtual-reality, jogl, oculus

I have recently done some game development using Java and OpenGL (with the JOGL library), and I was thinking about trying to learn how to develop on an Oculus GO. However, all guides seem to assume that the developer is going to use Unity. Is it possible to develop Oculus GO applications with Java and OpenGL directly? Is there any good documentation or guides for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the [Oculus Mobile SDK documentation](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/mobilesdk/latest/concepts/book-intro/):

> The Oculus Mobile SDK includes libraries, tools, and resources for native development for Oculus Go and Gear VR.
>
> **SDK Contents**
>
> - VrApi for third-party engine integration (not required for Unity or Unreal).
> - Native application framework for building high-performance VR Applications from scratch.
> - Native project sample applications and source to provide reference model for creating your own VR applications.
> - Tools and resources to assist with native development.
>
>   ...
>
> **Developing for Oculus Go and Gear VR**
>
> For the most part, developing apps for Oculus Go and Gear VR is the same.

So yes, development without an existing engine like Unity is supported, and the Oculus site provides documentation about how to set up your Java development environment to do this, along with sample projects.

In future, please do not neglect to read the manufacturer's published documentation when you have a question about what their products support - they're the best authorities on this topic.

Comment: Thank you, but after taking a closer look at that documentation it seems that most applications mostly use C++, is it possible to write an Oculus GO app in Java, and generate the 3d graphics using some java bindings with opengl?

Comment: Sure — at minimum, you can make a shim of native code that performs the low-level work you need, and exposes those methods to a Java program where the bulk of your game loop and logic live. But now we're no longer dealing with a problem that's Oculus Go / VR / game development specific. You can consult general programming guides for interfacing between Java and native code to proceed from here.